# How can one debug beachball instances in SwiftUI updates?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have what I thought would be a simple SwiftUI change to an app I'm building, but when I add the new view the app beach balls on startup and again on subsequent updates, even tho this view has yet to be wired to any data.

The main window view is as follows:

```
  var body: some View {

    VStack {
      manualOverrideView
        .frame(height: 160)
      VSplitView {
        StatusView(viewModel: statusViewModel)
          .frame(minHeight: 40, idealHeight: 50, maxHeight: 75)

        standingsTable()
      }
      .onChange(of: viewModel.sortOrder) {
        viewModel.standings.sort(using: $0)
      }
      ConnectionStatusView()
        .frame(height: 20)
    }
}
```

The `manualOverrideView` is the additional view that when I comment it out everything is fine, but when its included it beachballs.  Its defined as:

```
var manualOverrideView: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
      HStack {
        ForEach(0..<8) { _ in
          LightControlView()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Which contains multiples of this view:

```
struct LightControlView: View {

  var light: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
      .fill(.blue)
      .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
  }

  let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 50.0

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("deviceID")
      light
      HStack {
        Button {

        } label: {
          Text("1st Button")
            .frame(width: buttonWidth)
        }
        Button {

        } label: {
          Text("2nd Button")
            .frame(width: buttonWidth)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have yet to even wire it to a viewModel with the various states (count of number of devices, light state) and yet it makes what was a functioning app have unacceptable beach balling.  I have removed various modifiers and such and have yet to determine the culprit.  It does appear related to the number of LightControlView in the scroll view, but even with 8 its unacceptable performance.  What have I mucked up here?

Comment: Which `Instruments` have you tried? You can use a variety of them to diagnose a beachball. Also, have you tried removing elements of the view hierarchy until you find which one is the culprit?

Comment: I've tried the SwiftUI instrument and the threads.  The manualOverrideView takes ~220us to build, but the individual LightControlView is on the order of 8-10us.  Am not sure how to use the threads one to investigate the beachball.  Do you of a link that explains it well?  Yes, I've removed each part of the offending view to see what makes it fall over.  Trimming the ForEach to 1 or 2 makes it work fine.  At 8 its bad.  At 16 its horrible.  Other modifiers or elements removed seem to have no effect.

Comment: You could try using the `TimeProfiler` to see what's bogging it down. I think you should provide a [mre] that others can run. Otherwise, it's just speculation.

Comment: Yeah, all the time seems to be spent deep in the swiftui runtime.  Was hoping someone with more experience would point out something obvious to them but not to me that I'm doing wrong.  But it looks like the minimum reproducible project is the next step.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Found the obvious answer.  use LazyHStack and the beachballs disappear